# redrawing just a part in android view

Tags: android, view, redraw

I extended a View and call the invalidate() method to force redrawing. I only redraw a part off the View, but everything else is black.

How can I stop clearing the screen before onDraw() is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use invalidate(Rect) or invalidate(left, top, right, bottom)

Comment: Thx, I didn't see that by myself.

Comment: This method is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this work.
As I have used `invalidate(Rect)`. In `onDraw(Canvas)`, u can find the canvas height and width , the same as the view bounds. Canvas clip bounds is the same.

I think this might be work with a view group , but not a view.